# Bash: Find a string before another string in a file

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I am trying to find the preceding string before another string. For example:

```
StringA <stuff 1>
StringA <stuff 2>
StringD
...
StringB <stuff 3>
StringA <stuff 4>
StringA <stuff 5>
StringA <stuff 6>
StringD
StringB <stuff 7>
```

I want to find all the "StringA" that JUST preceeds StringB in the file.

The output in this example would be:

```
StringA <stuff 2>
StringA <stuff 6>
```

I am able to do find the line numbers of all the StringB by using: grep -n "StringB"

Then I can use sed -n 1,$line_numberp which makes me go from line 1 to the line of StringB. I do grep "StringA" | tail -n1

This seems to be work but is a bit cumbersome. Is there any better way to achieve the desired result please?

Comment: What about 4 and 5?  Those precede as B as far as I know.

Comment: I am just looking for the previous one, the only last one before stringB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With awk :

```
awk '/^StringB/ { if(lastline ~ /^StringA/) {print lastline }} {lastline=$0}' $file
```

StringA and StringB can be regular expressions.

Comment: One issue, if the last line of the file is StringA (and no StringB after it), it seems to print the last StringA. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
grep "\(StringA\|StringB\)" $file_name | grep -B 1 StringB | grep StringA
```

Comment: @perreal I thought about that, but didn't use it because it's unlikely op is asking about actual strings matching `String[AB]`

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '/String[AB]/!d' input | 
   sed -n -e '/StringA/{:l /StringA/h;n;/StringB/{x;p;b};bl}'
```

With comments:

```
sed '/String[AB]/!d' input |      # remove lines not containing StringA/B
   sed -n -e '/StringA/{          # if line contains StringA, then
      :l                          # loop until StringB
          /StringA/h;             # keep the most recent A in the hold space
          n;                      # read a newline (overwrite pattern space)
          /StringB/!bl;           # loop up...
          x;p;b                   # get the most recent A, and print
   }'
```

Comment: I wish I wrote that sed script!

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;$!N;/^StringA/!D;/^\(StringA\).*\n\1/D;/.*StringB/!ba;P;D' file
```

This removes duplicate `StringA` lines retaining the last and when encountering a `StringB` line prints out the first string in the pattern space.